# Rails cron job not running using whenever on Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cron, whenever

I'm currently using whenever gem for running my Sidekiq worker. It's perfectly fine when I'm running the Sidekiq worker but when I run it in background using cron it's not working.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.6.0-slim

RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y \
    # Needed for certain gems
    build-essential \
    # Needed for postgres gem
    libpq-dev \
    # install cron for cronjobs
    cron \
    # Others
    nodejs \
    vim-tiny \   
    # The following are used to trim down the size of the image by removing unneeded data
    && apt-get clean autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf \
      /var/lib/apt \
      /var/lib/dpkg \
      /var/lib/cache \
      /var/lib/log

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile

COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

ADD . /app

RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development' && /etc/init.d/cron restart 

CMD bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres:alpine
  volumes:
   - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
 redis:
  image: redis:5.0.7
  command: redis-server
  ports: 
    - "6379:6379"
 sidekiq:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  depends_on:
    - redis
  volumes: 
    - .:/app 
 web:
  build: .
  command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
  volumes:
   - .:/app
  ports:
   - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
   - db
   - redis
   - sidekiq
```

**schedule.rb**

```
set :environment, "development"

every 1.minute do
  runner "User.create"
end
```

When I run `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` and I access the web image using `docker exec -it <container-id> sh`

`crontab -e` returns

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /app/config/schedule.rb at: 2019-12-16 03:00:58 +0000

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /app && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''User.create'\'''

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /app/config/schedule.rb at: 2019-12-16 03:00:58 +0000
```

It should create a user every minute. I tried running this manually and it managed to create a user. I wonder why it's not running from cron

Comment: If you `docker exec` into your running container, can you verify that `cron` is running?

Comment: I check /etc/init.d/cron status it's not running then I start it manually using /etc/init.d/cron start but the job still not running. I wonder it's not running by default but I already added cron to run as part of Dockerfile

Comment: Cron won't be running.  A Docker container runs only a single process, and yours is running Sidekiq.  Run the cron job in a separate container, or use a gem like sidekiq-cron that can run scheduled jobs inside the Sidekiq worker.

Comment: (`RUN` commands don't persist running processes, so `RUN /etc/init.d/... start` doesn't actually have any effect.)

Comment: You could use the docker friendly "cron" gem [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask)